# How to find all TestScript items for a HL7 FHIR Server (v4)

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am learning about HL7 and I am trying to find out more about the TestScript resources.

As I understand it, using the TestScript resource, I can find all tests available on a FHIR server.

So I found a test server (https://vonk.fire.ly).

And I request the TestScript resource which returns a Bundle resource and it shows it has 7 items in the **searchset**

First question is how do I get the other 6 items?

Other websites I've found suggested there should be a Bundle.link with relation=next, but I don't see that in the response I get.

The second question:

I found this website: https://www.projectcrucible.org/, which will run all tests on the server you give it.

Now if I enter https://vonk.fire.ly, it manages to find a ton of tests.

My question is how does it get all those tests?

My understanding from HL7 FHIR is that based on the available resources, I should be able to find all those tests too. But I can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The vonk.fire.ly server only has 7 scripts.  When you query it, you get back one Bundle which contains 7 entries.  Each entry has one TestScript.  There are no other pages to retrieve which is why there's no 'next' link.  When you us projectcrucible.org, it must be grabbing TestScripts from somewhere other than just the vonk server.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the Crucible server's dashboard is a bit strange. I'll have to look at it again to see how it should be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a search, you get back a FHIR Bundle with entries for each resource that fulfilled your query. The Vonk server sends back 10 resources per page, so if only 7 resources match, you just get 1 Bundle without a next link.

The Vonk server is called a test server, because you can test your FHIR client against it. Vonk does not test anything itself - other than validating the incoming data - but will store data that you send to it, and responds to queries. So even though Vonk has 7 TestScript resources, they are just data that is stored.

The Crucible project is a testing platform that is set up to test FHIR servers. Crucible does not load the TestScript resources from the server you want to test, but uses its own tests.

Comment: Ah ok, so I'm incorrectly interpretting the Crucible website. I thought I could enter the URL of a FHIR server and Crucible will find out which tests are available on that server and allow me to execute those tests. 

But if that's not what it's doing, then it's just weird. Not sure what exactly it does then. 

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You can indeed enter the URL of a FHIR server, and then Crucible will give you a set of their test suites to choose from and test that server with. This ensures that all servers are tested with the same test sets, otherwise you can never really compare the capabilities of those servers.

Comment: So crucible will run it's own set of tests against the FHIR server I enter?
Regardless of what's in the server's own TestScript resource?

Comment: Yes. Crucible will check the server's CapabilityStatement to see whether it claims to support certain interactions, and you can choose which test suites to run yourself. But other than that, the tests in the suites are Crucible's own tests.